# Auto-reload and HTML Changes

Tags: angularjs, playframework-2.0, typesafe-activator

I'm developing an app that uses the Play framework (via Activator) on the server-side and Angular.js on the client. The problem is that html/js/asset changes I make do not show up until I stop and start the 'activator start' process.

This is a huge drag and takes away a lot of efficiency that is gained when developing on the client-side.

How do I make activator / play reload the site whenever a file is change din  the /assets folder tree?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`activator start` starts the application in **production** mode. Once in production mode, changing source files and assets will **not** affect the running application until it is restarted. In order to auto-reload you need to be in development mode: `activator run`.

Comment: Thanks. I wish they chose more descriptive names but so it goes.